# SharePoint -new page layout is not showing in Ribbon- Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working on SharePoint 2013 online. I have multiple site under a site collection. I have created new Page Layout using Design Manager in SharePoint ....i.e. SharePoint settings--> Design Manager--> Edit Page Layout --> Create New Page Layout... output of this action created html and aspx file. I have check in, publish it and finally approve it. now when i go to site under site collection, i want to change the page layout of a page so i went settings --> edit page--> Ribbon --> page layout but i cannot see my newly created page layout in the list... please help me out?? what I am missing .

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I  go to "Page layouts and site templates" page under Site Settings for site in which I want to use this page layout, over there I added my newly created custom page layout to show in Ribbon--> page layout list